# Chat server stops working

Tags: java, sockets, port

I have created a normal chat program which has just a server and a client class. I run the server at my end. The chat clients are run from different machines. In my program, I've specified a random port number which all the clients use a socket connection to connect to the server that runs on my machine. The first issue is that I've to disable firewall to get this working (probably, the firewall blocks the port I give). How to specify a port number that firewall can accept? Do I HAVE to open a port myself?

Secondly, after disabling firewall, everything works but all of a sudden, the connection is lost. None of the clients can send messages. What could possible be the reason for this? Not sure if it is caused due to the port I select.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set Socket connection timeout properly using `this.socket.setSoTimeout(timeOut);`
 to prevent timeout which must be causing connection loss.

In order to allow socket comunication through firewall go through this document : http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Allow-a-program-to-communicate-through-Windows-Firewall

Comment: The firewall one worked! Thanks! I just had to add that program separately. Regarding the timeout, since I'm using Swing framework, could you suggest a way to keep the socket connection alive till the frame window is closed?